# Ionic Android: Take camera photo and send it to the server

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have been struggling for a few days with taking a photo with the phone camera, using Ionic and Android device, and sending it to the server in a post request. Optionally, I want to display the image to the screen.
I read a lot of previous posts with similar problems, but none of the solutions worked for me. I want to mention that I am quite new to the ionic world, so I am still learning. Maybe it is a stupid problem that I cannot see. 
Before adding the code that I tried, I want to list the things that I have tried so far:

- Used FILE_URL and DATA_URL for the **destinationType** option
- Manually convert the image to base 64
- Used **domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(b64img)** in the **.html** file

Please, see below the code that I tried:

This is the code for taking the photo:

```js
const options: CameraOptions = { // photo options
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
} // take picture
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        this.imageData = imageData;
        this.image = ( < any > window).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(imageData);
        //extra http://localhost/file.. and I slice it to remove extra chars
        this.image = this.image.slice(27);
    },
    (err) => {
        this.helperService.showAlert(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
```

This is the code for uploading the photo to the server:

```js
upload() { // upload method
    let url = 'url/to/post';
    const date = new Date().valueOf();
    const imageName = date + '.jpeg';
    console.log(this.imageData);
    -- - > undefined
    //slice it to remove extra chars
    this.imageData = this.imageData.slice(27);
    const imageBlob = this.dataURItoBlob(this.imageData);
    const imageFile = new File([imageBlob], imageName, {
        type: 'image/jpeg'
    });
    let postData = new FormData();
    postData.append('file', imageFile);
    let data: Observable < any > = this.httpClient.post(url, postData);
    data.subscribe((result) => {
        this.helperService.showSuccess(result);
    });
}
```

And this is the blob function:

```js
dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    const byteString = window.atob(dataURI);
    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    const int8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        int8Array[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const blob = new Blob([int8Array], {
        type: 'image/jpeg'
    });
    return blob;
}
```

This is my HTML file:

```html
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
        <img [src]="DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(image)">
    </ion-grid>
    <ion-button (click)="upload()" color="success">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

**Problems:**

1. The photo is not displayed on the screen and my image is Undefined - I tried both with and without DomSanitizer
2. this.imageData is undefined inside the **upload()** method

This is the reference post that I followed, but I cannot manage to see the problems:
[Capture and upload image to server using Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720492/capture-and-upload-image-to-server-using-ionic-4)

Looking at this reference post, I sliced even the extra characters displayed in front of the image, but I did not manage to solve the problems.

Let me know if I should add any other information. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I manage to display the image on the screen by using:

```
let b64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  this.image = b64;
```

instead of

```
this.image = (<any>window).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(imageData);
```

Unfortunately, this.imageData is still undefined, and I cannot figure out why.
Update: Looks like the photo is sent to bakend now, but its size is 0 and backend (which is Nodejs) cannot use it. What should I do? Should I parse it in some way? 
Thank you!